# Accidently Deleted System files on Nxt 2.0. How to restore system files?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt

I have accidentally deleted the system files from my NXT 2.0. It is making a continuous clicking sound. How to I restore system files. I have the system files, but my computer can't detect it!

Please help soon!

Answer (score 2):

You need to reload the firmware. If you use NXT-G, this can be found under the Tools->Update Firmware menu.